# OWL : Does disjoint "general class axiom" via a property only works if classes themselves are disjointed?

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege

For example 1 :

- Classes : **A and B**.
- Property : **hasValue**.
- Axiom : **hasValue some A disjointWith hasValue some B**.
- Individual : **user1**.
- **user1 hasValue A**.
- **user1 hasValue B**.

Protege reasoner (HermiT) throws **no** error.

For example 2 :

- Classes : **A and B**.
- **A disjoint with B**.
- Property : **hasValue**.
- Axiom : **hasValue some A disjointWith hasValue some B**.
- Individual : **user1**.
- **user1 hasValue A**.
- **user1 hasValue B**.

Protege reasoner (HermiT) throws error.

Shouldn't *"hasValue some A disjointWith hasValue some B"* alone be sufficient to throw error in eg 1's case?

EDIT : example 1's reasoner result is wrong. As @Henriette Harmse showed below reasoner will throw error.

I was doing declaring Axiom a little differently than what I wrote above. I declared axiom as *"hasValue some B DisjointWith hasValue some
(P and (not (B)))"*, where P is parent class of both A and B. (Full sample ontology below.) If you import it in protege and run, you'll not get error.

It seems :

- "hasValue some B DisjointWith hasValue some A"
- "hasValue some B DisjointWith hasValue some (P and (not (B)))"

**are not equivalent statements.**

Sample ontology :

```
@prefix : <http://test.org/#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://test.org/> .

<http://test.org/> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://test.org/#hasValue
:hasValue rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://test.org/#A
:A rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf :P .


###  http://test.org/#B
:B rdf:type owl:Class ;
   rdfs:subClassOf :P .


###  http://test.org/#P
:P rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://test.org/#USER
:USER rdf:type owl:Class .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://test.org/#A
:A rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :A .


###  http://test.org/#B
:B rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
            :B .


###  http://test.org/#user1
:user1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
       :hasValue :A ,
                 :B .


#################################################################
#    General axioms
#################################################################

[ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
  owl:onProperty :hasValue ;
  owl:someValuesFrom :A ;
  owl:disjointWith [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                     owl:onProperty :hasValue ;
                     owl:someValuesFrom [ owl:intersectionOf ( :P
                                                               [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                                                                 owl:complementOf :A
                                                               ]
                                                             ) ;
                                          rdf:type owl:Class
                                        ]
                   ]
] .


[ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
  owl:onProperty :hasValue ;
  owl:someValuesFrom :B ;
  owl:disjointWith [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                     owl:onProperty :hasValue ;
                     owl:someValuesFrom [ owl:intersectionOf ( :P
                                                               [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                                                                 owl:complementOf :B
                                                               ]
                                                             ) ;
                                          rdf:type owl:Class
                                        ]
                   ]
] .


###  Generated by the OWL API (version 4.5.9.2019-02-01T07:24:44Z) https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi
```

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I think your intuition is right. If something can't have both an A and a B, but does have an A and a B, there should be an inconsistency.

Comment: Please can you provide the actual ontology?

Comment: Caution: you have A and B in your example as both class names and fillers for properties. A disjoint with B and user1 hasValue A do not refer to the same A. That's punning - there's an individual named A and a class named A. The disjoint axiom applies to classes, not individual fillers. I suspect your examples don't match what Protege is working on. Please post the actual ontologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried this now myself and for your first example I get an inconsistency with the following explanation:

[image: Explanation of inconsistency]

Here is the actual ontology giving the inconsistency. I will need to see your actual ontology to understand why you are not getting an inconsistency.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#"
 xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:untitled-ontology-9="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9"/>

  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#hasValue"/>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#A"/>    

  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#B"/>

  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#a">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#A"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>

  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#b">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#B"/>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>

  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#user1">
    <hasValue rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#a"/>
    <hasValue rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#b"/>
    </owl:NamedIndividual>

  <owl:Restriction>
    <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#hasValue"/>
    <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#A"/>
    <owl:disjointWith>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#hasValue"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/henri/ontologies/2022/6/untitled-ontology-9#B"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
      </owl:disjointWith>
  </owl:Restriction>
</rdf:RDF>
```

**Update after reviewing ACTUAL ontology**

The main problem is that you stated the GCI you used incorrectly. What you said you used are substantially different from what you actually used.

What you said used: `hasValue some A disjointWith hasValue some B`
What you actually used:

```
hasValue some A DisjointWith hasValue some (P and (not (A)))

hasValue some B DisjointWith hasValue some (P and (not (B)))
```

To understand why your GCIs do not have the desired effect, I have drawn an example Venn diagram:

[image]

Note that `hasValue some A DisjointWith hasValue some (P and (not (A)))` states that there is no individual `x` that belongs to both the set `hasValue some A` and the set `hasValue some (P and (not (A)))`. It does however allow for the possibility that you have an individual `user1` that is related via `hasValue` to an individual in set `A` and that is related via `hasValue` to an individual in set `B`. This is because nothing prohibits the sets `hasValue some A` (to which `user1 hasValue A` belongs) and `hasValue some B` (to which `user1 hasValue B` belongs)` to overlap. To prohibit this, you have to add the following GCI:

`hasValue some A DisjointWith hasValue some B`

**How to get a inconsistency using you GCIs**

To get an inconsistency using your GCIs, you have to have an individual that  actually belong to the disjoint sets you defined. I.e.,

Define individual `x` as follows:

```
:x rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
        [ owl:intersectionOf ( :P
                               [ rdf:type owl:Class ;
                                 owl:complementOf :A
                               ]
                             ) ;
          rdf:type owl:Class
        ] .
```

and then define `user2`:

```
:user2 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ;
   :hasValue :A ,
             :x .
```

You will get an inconsistency with the following explanation:

[image]

Comment: I added a smaple ontology of how I was getting error and some explanations. Do you have any idea why those 2 statements are not equivalent?